# I want to use scrapy just download .jpg picture

Tags: python, scrape

I have a question I just want to down load .jpg image. I used the follow code but I found that I still download .png or .gif picture. can anyone help me ?

```
#coding:utf-8
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from jianshu.items import JianshuItem
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler  import  CrawlerProcess


class jiansider(Spider):
    name = "jiantu"
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls= [
    "https://tieba.baidu.com/p/5227563995"
    ]


    def parse(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//div/img/@src').extract()
        item = JianshuItem()
        item['image_url'] = response.xpath('//div/img/@src').extract()
        for url in item['image_url']:



            list_photo = url.split('.')
            photo_type = list_photo[len(list_photo)-1]
            print photo_type
            if photo_type != 'jpg':
                #print url
                item['image_url'].remove(url)
                #print "delete1"


        yield item
        total_page = response.xpath('//span[@class="red"]/text()').extract()
        now_page = response.xpath('//li/span[@class="tP"]/text()').extract()
        tpa=total_page[len(total_page)-1]
        npa=now_page[len(now_page)-1]
        tpage= int(tpa)
        npage= int (npa)

        print "present page -----"
        print npage
        print "total page ------"
        print tpage
        starturls = 'https://tieba.baidu.com/p/5227563995?pn='
        if npage != tpage:
            npage = npage+1
            new_url = '%s%s'%(starturls,npage)
            print "new_url is ------------"
            print new_url       
        if new_url:
            yield  scrapy.Request(new_url,callback = self.parse)
```

I use if page!= .jpg to avoid download photo whose type isn't jpg but I failed. Is somebody can tell me why and help me to deal with it ?

Comment: What comes up when you `print photo_type`?

Comment: also, you can do `url.endswith('.jpg')`